# How do I search for a point in a text file *after* a specific other point?

Tags: java

I have one integer, `char2`, that has a certain index value of around 3 million. I'm trying to find the string "traits" in the same file, as relating to `char2`. However, searching for the string "traits" returns a value of 1.5 million, obviously from some earlier point in the file. How can I run a search for traits such that it is greater than 3 million, and occurs directly after `char2`?

```
int charloc2 = (fileText.indexOf("traits"))
```

Comment: Could you post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the other version of `indexOf` that starts the search at a given index:

```
int charloc2 = (fileText.indexOf("traits", char2));
```